# Handling forward 1:n relationships with drools

Tags: drools

I'm trying to write a rule that applies on a set of facts based on the content of another fact. I have simplified the problem to a House with Rooms. Let's say we have something like:

```
House(id);
Room(id, houseId, floor, side, paint);
```

Now, if I want to trigger a rule on all the Houses with all Rooms in left side painted on green I would write something like:

```
rule "Left side 1st floor green"
when
   $h: House()
   forall($r: Room(houseId=$h.id, floor==1, side=="left")
       Room(id == $r.id, paint == "green"))
then
   //Do whatever on rule triggering
end
```

But what if the objects in the working memory are organized in this way:

```
House(id, List<> roomIds);
Room(id, floor, side, paint);
```

How can I write a foreach condition (or any other approach) to make the same consideration on the rooms for a given house? Does it make sense or should I better try to reorganize my objects in advance to have the relationship expressed the other way around?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming in `House` the `List<> roomIds` is a List of `Room.id`(s), then you can do something like:

```
rule "Left side 1st floor green"
when
   $h: House(/* .. conditions for specific house? .. */)
   $r : Room($h.roomIds contains id, floor==1, side=="left", paint == "green")
then
   //Do whatever on rule triggering
end
```

However this is a bit unefficient, and I do agree as others replied, changing a bit the business/data model would make writing this kind of rule more idiomatic and more efficient. For example if the House did have the list of Rooms, you can also use OOPath to navigate as desired the structure.

Comment: Yes, Actually that was what my question was about. Changing the data model was not easy to achieve and therefore I wanted to know if there was some way to express the same based on the current data model. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

According to your rule, you do not have houses with rooms. According to what you have defined you have houses in your working memory and you have rooms in your working memory and you try to match these.

Why don't you have a List of Rooms in your House? That would make much more sense:

```
House(houseId, List<Room> rooms)
Room(roomId, floor, side, paint)
```

Then your rule would be:

```
rule "Left side 1st floor green"
  when
   $houses : House ($rooms : rooms, $houseId : houseId)
   $room : Room ($roomId : roomId, floor==1 && side=="left" && paint == "green") from $rooms
  then
   //Rule would trigger for each room left side 1st floor green rooms
   System.out.println("House "+$houseId+" has following left side 1st floor green room: "+$roomId);
end
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Actually I wanted to know if there was another option (changing the datamodel was the only thing that came to my mind).